# HTML5 drag and drop - how to capture and swap data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

so I followed an HTML5 drag and drop example here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dataTransfer

and created the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5zT/

The problem is, I want to be able to essentially swap the entire element, and its data attributes, not just the inner html. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just swap the elements themselves, not serializing and reparsing new elements.

```
        var parent = this.parentNode,
            insertionPoint, elem = this;

        do {
            elem = elem.nextSibling;
        } while (elem && elem !== draggedItem);

        insertionPoint = elem ? this : this.nextSibling;
        parent.insertBefore(draggedItem, insertionPoint);
        draggedItem = null;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5zT/11/

Comment: hmm - there's something a little bit off. How would you set it up so that it is not swapping the elements, but actually adding them before or after, depending on its previous position. In other words, if you have 1,2,3 and you drag one over 3, the order should be 2,3,1. If you have 1,2,3 and you drag 3 over 1, the order should be 3,1,2. I know I said swap before - but really what I want to do is sort of shuffle the order.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5zT/7/:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(draggedItem).clone(true,true));
$(draggedItem).replaceWith($(this).clone(true,true));
```

But `.clone(true,true)` should copy the event listeners too, but it doesn't, so drag and drop stops working. I solved it creating the function `addEvents`:

```
function addEvents(){
    $('.segmentListItem').each(function(index){
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragstart',handleDragStart,false);
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('drop',handleDrop,false);
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragover',handleDragOver,false);
    });
}
```

and then:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(draggedItem).clone(true,true));
$(draggedItem).replaceWith($(this).clone(true,true));
addEvents();
```

**Edit:**

I have fixed the problem with event listeners, and I have adapted your code to jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5zT/12/

Comment: `jQuery#clone` only copies over jQuery events. jQuery has no access (how could it have :P) to normal event listeners so it cannot copy them.

Comment: @Esailija you are right, when I realized that I fixed it on http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5zT/12/, adding the event listeners using Jquery.